# Teamcity change node in xml file

Tags: powershell, configuration, build, teamcity

i need to change node (true or false because of configuration)in xml file on a remote computer, working in Teamcity, wrote the following function

```
 function Set-layout($hiddenfunctionality)
 {

$properties = Resolve-Path ".\vsphere\properties.ps1"

. $properties

#Read env.properties
$configFilePath = Resolve-Path ".\environment\prod-env\env.properties"
Write-Host $configFilePath

$file = resolve-path("$configFilePath")
[xml]$doc = Get-Content $file

$node = $doc.SelectSingleNode("/project/property[@name='backend.server']")
$backend_ip = $node.value

$layoutRel = Resolve-Path ".\layout\layoutRel.ps1"
#Remote-Copy $layoutRel "\\$backend_ip\install"
Copy-Item $layoutRel "\\$backend_ip\install"

$dom_user = [string]($domain_name+ "\" + $domain_username)
$Connection = @{"server" = $backend_ip; "username" = $dom_user; "password" = $domain_password}
$rem_command = 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned . c:\Empower\install\layoutRel.ps1 $hiddenfunctionality'
RemoteCommand $Connection $rem_command

   }
```

this function is working and it call the script which will change the value of the node "configuration/appSettings/add[@key='opentext.empower.site.enableHiddenFunctionality"

```
    Param ($hiddenfunctionality)
    Write-Host "Updating C:\Program Files\Opentext\Empower\Web\Web.config"
    [System.Xml.XmlDocument] $xd = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
    $file = resolve-path("C:\Program Files\Opentext\Empower\Web\web\Web.config")
    $xd.load($file)
     $xd.SelectNodes("configuration/appSettings/add[@key='opentext.empower.site.enableHiddenFunctionality']").Item(0).SetAttribute( 'value', $hiddenfunctionality)
    $xd.Save( $file)
     Write-Host "Done"
```

In my teamcity configs do the following string

```
       powershell . %teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\Build\CI_2.0\vsphere\env-handler.ps1; Set-layout $true
```

all it works, but field value in my file is empty, but should be true or false(

and i can't make a static true or false. it should be change because of some configurations in Teamcity

Maybe i can take the name of build configuration from teamcity anf if cat_1 than run "true" if cat_2 than "false" but i don't know how to do it

Comment: Just a wild stab, have you tried replacing $true with "true" when you call Set-Layout function. Maybe something is happening when the $true variable is passed along the scripts and the functions.

Comment: no, i dont try, you tell to try call function in teamcity "true" instead of $true?

Comment: yes, try that and see if anything happens

Answer (score 0):

So , i've found that my script layoutrel.ps1 which will chamge node, don't take the parameter $hiddenfunctionality why it can be? When i gave for $hiddenfunctionality="true" it works(